# What part of speech is 'closer' functioning as in 'I moved closer'?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

> 'I moved **closer**.'

At face value, 'closer' seems to be acting like an adjective; however, I don't see anything in the sentence to which it can refer. A friend suggested that 'to move closer', 'to move further', and friends are a family of phrasal verbs, but this seems like a cop out to me.

I think the most likely answer is that 'closer' is functioning as a comparative adverb. A very common error in colloquial English is to use an adjective in place of the adverbial form ('I am doing good' instead of 'I am doing well'). Correcting for this error yields 'I moved more closely'. Admittedly, this sounds awkward, but I think that has more to do with the uncommon phrasing than the technical integrity of the expression.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Yes. `I moved closer (to the place I mentioned earlier)`

Comment: You're right; `I moved more closely to the place I mentioned earlier` doesn't sound awkward at all. Adding a comparator makes all the difference!

Comment: I think what's meant is `more close` rather than `more closely`. Both would be adverbs, though.

Comment: Could it be a case of a [flat adverb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb)? At M-W seem to like those: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7epnfcHy5SA

Comment: I don't find any of the answers I see here very persuasive.  Maybe it's a "flat adverb", but does that make it an adverb?  Why count it as an adverb at all?  Why not an adjective that describes the result of some action?  "I moved the candles close." then, "The candles were close."  (Surely not *"The candles were closely.")

Comment: This sentence has been done things to. It means (and in a derivational theory it would be derived from) _I moved it ((to a place) where it is) closer_. This explains why the sentences Greg mentions have predicate adjectives -- the original is a predicate adjective. Generally speaking, if a very short English sentence is giving trouble, find what has been left out by looking for a longer sentence with the same words in it that means the same thing.

Comment: @JohnLawler In exactly the same way, one can argue that _away_ in _I moved away_ is an adjective: _I moved (myself) ((to a place) where I am) away._

Comment: In that particular case, it's a phrasal verb, and _away_ can be called an adverb, a particle, an adjective, or a preposition, depending on the theory you patronize. You pays your money and you takes your choice; not that it makes any difference what you call it. It's defined by its behavior as part of a phrasal verb, not by any imaginary part of speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Closer* in this sentence is the comparative of the adverb *close*.

*close* (adv.)

> at or to a short distance or time away

[[M-W]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/close)

Answer (score -1):

I believe 'closer' ad used is an adverb but not of manner,  as suggested by 'closely,' but an adverb of place. Consider that the word is adding information to the verb 'moved' regarding location.